# PowerApps Gallery not showing SharePoint data for users

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have a PowerApp that is a gallery showing a list from SharePoint and also an input mask for said list in SharePoint. The input part works flawlessly for me and my collegues, but the gallery part which should be showing the data from the SharePoint list is giving me a headache.

I can see the data from the SP list in the App. My colleagues with whom I shared the App only see a blank list.

When they first open the shared app they have to accept a prompt from the SharePoint connector & I have given them all access to the specific SharePoint list. Yet they still don't see anything in the PowerApp gallery that should show the SP data.

I checked the connections in the App setting and the SharePoint connection works. Also I can see the data. Although the connector is showing my personal SharePoint account, but afaik by granting the SharePoint access on the first opening of the App this should take care of that.

TLDR: 
PowerApp has a gallery that shows SP data and that works for me but not for the users whom I shared the App with. They only see a blank gallery. How do I fix that?

BR
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thankfully found the issue myself after some digging around in the settings. In the Advanced List setting the following option was not set to read all:

Item-level Permissions
Specify which items users can read and edit.

With this option correctly set everyone is now able to see the list items.

Have a great day and I hope this might help someone!